# Can I shorten the history of a git repository

Tags: git, git-repo, git-history

At first, I made a shallow-clone. After this, I found some old commits introducing some large files. For example, these old commits replaced a binary file again and again.

Now, I didn't want my local reposiotry containing these big changes. How can I shorten the history without recreating a new repository with `git clone --depth=10`?

```sh
# shallow clone
git clone --depth 100 ssh://git@10.7.222.111:/home/my_repository01.git
git log --oneline | wc -l  # the result is 100

# Now, how can I shorten the current history to 10? 
# Otherwise, I need to execute `git clone --depth=10` to recreate the repository.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`git fetch --depth=10`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt) to update the current shallow depth.

Comment: Amazing!  After exeucting `git fetch --depth=10 origin master`,  the result of `git log --oneline | wc -l` is 10. And I also found the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt). Many thanks!